# Segregate by class names types using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have input data like this:

```
TRectAdvanced
SVGConstants
TransferService
AccountController
MindMapDemo
SVGMindMapTool
TreeViewAdvancedTool
AccountService
TransferController
TreeViewTools
MindMapRectUtils
SVGUtils
TNodeAdvanced
TreeRectUtils
UMLSVGUtils
UniqueList
```

I should segregate names of classes by type (Service, Controller, DAO, Utils, List, Tool...).

Expected output:
(Order not important.)
How can I do? Can help me?

Output:

```
TRectAdvanced
TNodeAdvanced

MailConstants
SVGConstants

MindMapDemo

SVGMindMapTool
TreeViewAdvancedTool
TreeViewTool

MindMapRectUtils
TreeRectUtils
UMLSVGUtils
SVGUtils

UniqueList

AccountDAO
TransferDAO

AccountService
TransferService

AccountController
TransferController
```

Comment: You can try by using a custom comparator on the list of names in the input.

Comment: Use streams, with a `Collectors.groupingBy` collector, where the function is something that returns the "category", e.g. for `TRectAdvanced` it returns `Advanced`.

Comment: `names.stream().map(Pattern.compile(".*([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)$")::matcher).filter(Matcher::find).collect(groupingBy(m -> m.group(1), mapping(m -> m.group(), toList())))`

Comment: alternatively, you can use `names.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.replaceFirst(".*(?=\\p{Lu})", "")))`